# Move Background in AndEngine for a Racing Game

Tags: android, game-design, andengine

I am new to game development and AndEngine. I have small query about racing game. I am going to develop a bike racing game. For bike racing game we will move the background or the player. I am tried with andengine autoparallax background. But I didn't got the correct answer.

I need to do a background  like these screenshots in [SpeedMoto](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Game.SpeedMoto).

Can anyone help me to set the background.

Comment: So what's the question exactly?

Comment: I guess a common approach on such a game would be move only the background while your player stay at the center of the screen.

Comment: my question is how to move the background simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the camera to chase the Sprite object which is, in your case, the car.

```
mCamera.setChaseEntity(entity);
```

note that you will need to bigger background or zoom the camera.